# Python read txt file and create array list

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a txt file that I read line by line with my python code:

```
a = open("data.txt","r")
inputF = a.readlines()
for line in inputF:
   print(line)
```

my txt file is this:

```
Data: 7_8_2014
Name: Road
488597.653655, 4134910.76248
488813.848952, 4134609.01192
488904.303214, 4134480.54842
488938.462756, 4134422.3471
Name: Street
496198.193041, 4134565.19994
496312.413827, 4134568.14182
496433.652036, 4134568.08923
496559.933558, 4134547.91561
496782.196397, 4134527.70636
496923.636101, 4134512.56252
```

i would like to read this file txt and create a list array as this:

```
coordsList = [[Road, 488597.653655, 4134910.76248], 
          [Road, 488813.848952, 4134609.01192],
          [Road, 488904.303214, 4134480.54842],
          [Road, 488938.462756, 4134422.3471],
          [Street, 496198.193041, 4134565.19994],
          [Street, 496312.413827, 4134568.14182],
          [Street, 496433.652036, 4134568.08923],
          [Street, 496559.933558, 4134547.91561],
          [Street, 496782.196397, 4134527.70636],
          [Street, 496923.636101, 4134512.56252]]
```

for each tag "Name" into txt file.

With your (Anton vBR) help i have update my code in this way:

```
import arcpy
import os, sys
import io

with open('C:/Users/fdivito/Desktop/FinalProjectData/7_8_2014.txt', 'r') as content_file:
content = content_file.read()
i=0
output = []


for row in io.StringIO(content).readlines()[1:]: # skips first row
if row.startswith("Name"):
    #i = row.split(":")[1].strip()
    i+=1
else:
    output.append([i]+[float(item.strip()) for item in row.split(",")])

print(output)
```

but i have this error:
for row in io.StringIO(content).readlines()[1:]: # skips first row
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str

Comment: You need to check lines if they contains text Name and then act accordingly. You can use if "Name" in line language construct.

Comment: what are these numbers in your list?

Comment: You do realise that the data you have in your example file, bears no relation to the data you say you want in your list. That may cause some confusion.

Comment: I have fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**updated with names and convert to float**

How about something like this?

```
import io

string = u"""Data: 7_8_2014
Name: Road
488597.653655, 4134910.76248
488813.848952, 4134609.01192
488904.303214, 4134480.54842
488938.462756, 4134422.3471
Name: Street
496198.193041, 4134565.19994
496312.413827, 4134568.14182
496433.652036, 4134568.08923
496559.933558, 4134547.91561
496782.196397, 4134527.70636
496923.636101, 4134512.56252"""

output = []

#with open("pathtofile.txt") as file:
#    for row in file.readlines()[1:]
    #code here

for row in io.StringIO(string).readlines()[1:]: # skips first row
    if row.startswith("Name"):
        i = row.split(":")[1].strip()
    else:
        output.append([i]+[float(item.strip()) for item in row.split(",")])

output
```

Returns:

```
 [['Road', 488597.653655, 4134910.76248],
 ['Road', 488813.848952, 4134609.01192],
 ['Road', 488904.303214, 4134480.54842],
 ['Road', 488938.462756, 4134422.3471],
 ['Street', 496198.193041, 4134565.19994],
 ['Street', 496312.413827, 4134568.14182],
 ['Street', 496433.652036, 4134568.08923],
 ['Street', 496559.933558, 4134547.91561],
 ['Street', 496782.196397, 4134527.70636],
 ['Street', 496923.636101, 4134512.56252]]
```

Comment: Yes is perfect, but i would take also the value of tag "Name"

Comment: I have updated my code with your help, but i have error posted on my original code

Comment: @APPGIS was missing a u for unicode before the string u""" ... """, my answer is updated to work with python2 and 3 now

Answer (score 1):

python3 solutions:

```
`result_list = []
 with open(your_file, 'r') as file_:
    file_.readline() # skip the header, apparently you don't want it.

    for line in file_:
        if line.startswith('Name'):
            current_tag = line.strip().split()[-1] # assume that the tag as no space
          # else use split(':')[-1].strip()
            continue 
        result_list.append([current_tag] + line.strip().split(','))
```

`